# The method Sleep(int) is undefined for the type new Runnable(){} in Android

Tags: java, android, thread-sleep

I have used code from [Android recipe - create loading screen](http://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam?recipeId=1599) However, I am having problems using this.sleep() as I receive the error "The method Sleep(int) is undefined for the type new Runnable(){}" Other questions have stated that there is a problem with naming the class such as "Thread". This does not seem to be the case for my code though.

**Code**

```
public class LoadingScreenActivity extends Activity {

//Introduce an delay
    private final int WAIT_TIME = 2500;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    System.out.println("LoadingScreenActivity  screen started");
    setContentView(R.layout.loading_screen);
    findViewById(R.id.mainSpinner1).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){ 
    @Override 
        public void run() { 
              //Simulating a long running task
              this.Sleep(1000);
         System.out.println("Going to Profile Data");
      /* Create an Intent that will start the ProfileData-Activity. */
              Intent mainIntent = new Intent(LoadingScreenActivity.this,ProfileData.class); 
        LoadingScreenActivity.this.startActivity(mainIntent); 
        LoadingScreenActivity.this.finish(); 
    } 
    }, WAIT_TIME);
      }
}
```

Comment: What do you think the error means?

Answer (score 1):

What you're probably looking for is

```
Thread.sleep(1000);
```

Runnable is an Interface and does not have any implemented methods of it's own, only public void run(), which you have to override and implement.

Answer (score 0):

That code is simply wrong. It should be `Thread.sleep(1000)`, but even so, it's not correct, and it will produce an "Application not responding" error, because it's trying to pause the UI thread.

Please take some time and read a Java and Android book. You won't get anywhere following half-baked implementations from the Internet.